# Design pattern for self-referencing ordered tree of objects (C#/ASP.Net Core/EFCore)

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, recursive-datastructures

First I apologise if I should have been able to find this myself through search... I'm rusty and learning a lot of new stuff so I'm not even sure if I'm using the right terms to describe what I want - don't kick the noob please :)

Question: Part 1 - Specific scenario
I am trying to build classes to produce a tree of "goal objects", where

a) order matters and needs to be retained,

b) each goal object in the tree may stand alone as a single object, or comprise a collection of subgoals (and those subgoals further subgoals etc - let's say to a depth of 5 levels),

c) ability to edit the tree efficiently is necessary (including changing the order or index of any goal object, adding / removing / reordering / moving  subgoals, pruning/adding branches to the tree).
I can certainly work out a way to do this, but I strongly suspect my way will be highly inefficient both in terms of memory / processing and in terms of quantity of code required to manage the editing etc.

My question therefor: Can anyone point me to a design pattern or tutorial that will show me an efficient way to do this - or something similar that I can adapt? 
(I am currently working in C# & ASP.NET Core with EFCore pointing to SQLserver)

Part 2: Recommendations for a book / site that has an excellent set of fundamental design patterns suitable for C# would also be welcome.

Many thanks for any help you can offer. 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to answer my own questions:

Part 1: The closest I have found so far is the Composite design pattern, using an abstract class from which leaf and composite classes inherit. However, I think I would have to add to this a) mechanism to convert a leaf to a composite and vice versa, and b) from what I can see this pattern doesn't solve the "order matters and changes" constraint so I would have to implement some order index and manage changes in order - anyone has an efficient way to do these things?

Part 2: Found Gang of Four, and http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns, so consider part 2 closed but welcome any other suggestions obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not looking for a programming pattern, you are looking for a data structure.

Have a look at [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

That is a (quasi-)balanced tree which preserves ordering of its nodes, and all operations are logarithmic (that is, efficient).